# Finding multiple substrings in a string without iterating over it multiple times

Tags: python, string, full-text-search

I need to find if items from a list appear in a string, and then add the items to a different list. This code works:

```
data =[]
line = 'akhgvfalfhda.dhgfa.lidhfalihflaih**Thing1**aoufgyafkugafkjhafkjhflahfklh**Thing2**dlfkhalfhafli...'
_legal = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4',...] 
for i in _legal:
    if i in line:
        data.append(i)
```

However, the code iterates over `line` (which could be long) multiple times- as many times as there are item in `_legal` (which could be a *lot*). That's too slow for me, and I'm searching for a way to do it faster. `line` doesn't have any specific format, so using `.split()` couldn't work, as far as I know.
Edit: changed `line` so that it better represents the problems.

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in the list?

Comment: are the items of equal length?

Comment: @IoaTzimas No, all values in the list `_legal` are different.

Comment: probably a stretch, but a modified version of [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) might be able to achieve this in a single pass, especially if strings in `_legal` have common prefixes

Comment: Great. Do you want to much entire words, or they are random text in the list?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, their lengths vary.

Comment: For example thing1 will be found in the line as thing1 or abcthing1abc etc?

Comment: Is it a theoretical question (i.e. you're after big-O complexity) or is it a practical problem?

Comment: @IoaTzimas yes.

Comment: @Marat practical problem

Comment: @Marat your comment implies that Big-O complexity is not important in practical problems, which is painfully wrong

Comment: @DeepSpace best asymptotic complexity ignores constants and and considers only asymptotic case. In many practical situations, best big-O solution is suboptimal. Seeing people not understanding it is also painful sometimes.

Comment: You are looking for aho-corasick algorithm. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I could think of to improve is:

- Get all unique lengths of the words in `_legal`
- Build a dictionary of words from `line` of those particular lengths using a sliding window technique. The complexity should be `O( len(line)*num_of_unique_lengths )`, this should be better than brute force.
- Now look for each `thing` in the dictionary in O(1).

Code:

```
line = 'thing1 thing2 456 xxualt542l lthin. dfjladjfj lauthina '
_legal = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4', 't5', '5', 'fj la']
ul = {len(i) for i in _legal}
s=set()
for l in ul:
    s = s.union({line[i:i+l] for i in range(len(line)-l)})
print(s.intersection(set(_legal)))
```

Output:

```
{'thing1', 'fj la', 'thing2', 't5', '5'}
```

Comment: I added an answer based on your thinking. Feel free to copy it and let me know so that i will remove mine

Comment: @IoaTzimas Thanks. I thought I will add my own code and test things like words with spaces and added.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to build a very simple regex pattern, and use `re.findall()` to find/extract any matched words in the string.

```
import re

line = 'akhgvfalfhda.dhgfa.lidhfalihflaih**Thing1**aoufgyafkugafkjhafkjhflahfklh**Thing2**dlfkhalfhafli...'
_legal = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']

exp = re.compile(r'|'.join(_legal), re.IGNORECASE)
exp.findall(line)

>>> ['Thing1', 'Thing2']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work quite efficiently. It implements the suggestion from [@SomeDude given above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215060/843953)

```
lens=set([len(i) for i in _legal])
d={}
for k in lens:
    d[k]=[line[i:i+k] for i in range(len(line)-k)]
s=set(sum(d.values(), []))
result=list(s.intersection(set(_legal)))
```

for the following data (i changed "line" a bit as it returned an empty list due to uppecase in Thing1 and Thing2)

```
line = 'akhgvfalfhda.dhgfa.lidhfalihflaih**thing1**aoufgyafkugafkjhafkjhflahfklh**thing2**dlfkhalfhafli...'
_legal = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4',...]
```

Output is:

```
print(result)

['thing2', 'thing1']
```

Explanation:
We saved all possible lengths of the words in substrings. For these lengths, we created all possible substrings in text (set s). Finally we found common items in s and substrings, which is the answer to the question.

Comment: Quick observation, the `line` value in OP shows Thing1 and Thing2, in title case.

Comment: yes, i changed it a little, as it would return an empty list otherwise

Comment: Not being funny, I believe hacking source data to match a desired output is slightly frowned upon ...

Comment: Are you really in the philosophy of the question?

Comment: Implementing somebody else's answer as code without crediting them is also frowned upon... In fact, I'd go so far as to say it's pretty dishonest

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi you are right, i was inspired from SomeDude's answer. I added a credit. Please give any upvote to his answer instead of mine. Cheers