# Is it possible to find specified substrings in a string in one iteration or faster then O(n*m)?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity

I have a string and list of unique substrings. The problem is to identify, which substrings occur in our string.

It can be done simply with 2 nested loops.

```py
result = []
substrings = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs']
text = 'foo123123spameggsabcde'

for s in substrings:
    if s in text:
        result.append(s)
```

But it is slow, especially whith long string and many substrings. Is there a way to perform this more efficiently?

Comment: That is not `n^2` rather `n*m` where `m` denotes number of substrings.

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular expression without loop?

Comment: @TonyTannous Thank you for reply, i edited my question

Comment: @dmitryro I don't know, how to estimate complexity while using regular expressions

Comment: Hint: [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) string search algorithm.

Comment: I think that also the length of the substring should take into consideration when speaking of efficiency and complexity, think of a very long substrings.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Finding multiple substrings in a string without iterating over it multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214769/finding-multiple-substrings-in-a-string-without-iterating-over-it-multiple-times) How often do you see the same non-trivial question pop up twice between minutes of each other?! This is probably the first time I've seen such a thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SomeDude's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215060/843953) from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64214769/843953),
the following should work quite efficiently:

```
lens=set([len(i) for i in substrings])
d={}
for k in lens:
    d[k]=[text[i:i+k] for i in range(len(text)-k)]
s=set(sum(d.values(), []))
result=list(s.intersection(set(substrings)))

print(result)

['foo', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

Explanation:
We saved all possible lengths of the words in substrings. For these lengths, we created all possible substrings in text (set s). Finally we found common items in s and substrings, which is the answer to the question.